# Verificar se está ativo a opção de limpar o cache ao fechar o navegador

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet, adobe-flex

Eu tenho uma aplicação em **Adobe FLEX** e como alguns cliente possuem computadores muito ruins a limpeza de cache automática está atrapalhando na performance da aplicação, gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de verificar se essa opção está marcada no navegador. Existe alguma possibilidade de ser feito em javascript ou em outra linguagem?

Minha ideia é verificar se está marcado e caso esteja enviar uma mensagem para o cliente informando que ele desabilite a opção.

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver problemas de cache nos arquivos, geralmente adiciono um número da versão da aplicação com uma interrogação no inicio como se fosse uma querystring tipo:

```
<script src="meuscript.js?v=131"></script>
```

Isso pode resolver o problema que esta acontecendo em sua aplicação. Você pode por este número para ser gerado no momento da execução ou seja um número randômico onde vai forçar com que toda vez que página for atualizada forçara com que o arquivo seja novamente carregado.

Comment: Sua resposta considerou que é um app em Flex ?

Comment: Não apenas mostrei qual solução eu utilizo para lidar com problemas de cache. Ele pode tentar seguir o mesmo conceito para conseguir resolver o problema. Ou verificar em outra pergunta que tem alguns códigos javascript que podem ajuda-lo: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922910/force-browser-to-clear-cache]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13107058/3629273

Comment: eu acho que sua resposta não se aplica a este contexto

Comment: Olá Rodolfo, para o meu caso não se aplica pois eu preciso saber se esta ativo essa opção no navegador para solicitar que o usuário desabilite, mas mesmo assim obrigado pela ajuda.